# JQuery - Ajax - Set Request Header - DocuSign

Tags: ajax, header, docusignapi

Afternoon!

I a trying to send a get request usng jquery/ajax and I need to set headers. When I try setting the headers using Chrome's REST app, it woks fine and returns what I need.

I am watcing the headers in Firebug hen I run this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlLoginCall,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
    success: function(r){
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

The above works fine and I get a failed response, since I am not including the authorization info in the headers. But it at least shows me something in Firebug that I am setting the header Accept.

When I try to add the X-DocuSign-Authentication header, i get the failed alert, but nothing comes up in Firebug:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlLoginCall,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': jsonLoginCall},
    success: function(r){
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Any ideas would b helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You will still need the Accept and Content Type headers: headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}, Also can you use fiddler to see what is really being sent back and forth on your app it will help you greatly.

Comment: There is no session based auth for DS API.  If you put your code in the front end you will expose your integrator key and the users' token.  I think you should have your front end call your controller that in turn calls DS API.

Comment: Whe I look t fiddler, using the custom headers that docusign requires, I see: OPTIONS /restapi/v2/login_information HTTP/1.1, when I ue just the standard, I see: GET /restapi/v2/login_information HTTP/1.1

Comment: Doing some research it seems this is a CORs issue. which confuses me, since their API says you can use javascript to utilize their API. I am pretty new to all of this, so I could be missing something obvious.